# How can I set up connection with DVR and decode the data?

Tags: java, android

My system consists of a digital video recorder (dvr) and two cameras, which are connected with dvr. The dvr works as server also (connected to LAN). To the system was included an android application, where I put info about server, port, user name and password (I can add accounts using server software). The application streams video from cameras. I can also connect with dvr via http (only IE), then it show activeX application.

What I'm to do is write similar application, but I stuck into a problem - how can I fetch the video stream from dvr? I'm no expert with Java and tried connect with dvr, unsuccessfully.

Here is my code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class VideoStream
{

final static int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024000;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
    {
        protected  PasswordAuthentication  getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            System.out.println("Authenticatting...");
            PasswordAuthentication p=new PasswordAuthentication("login", "password".toCharArray());
        return p;       
        }
    });
    Socket s = new Socket();
    String host = "192.168.80.107"; //192.168.80.107
    PrintWriter s_out = null;
    BufferedReader s_in = null;
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;

    try
    {
        s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 34599));
        System.out.println("Is connected? : " + s.isConnected());

        s_out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        s_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        //bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    }
    catch(UnknownHostException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    byte[] b = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    //bufferedInputStream.read(b);

    int bytesRead = 0;
    System.out.println("Reading... \n");
    while((bytesRead = s_in.read()) > 0)
    {
        System.out.println(s_in.readLine());
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

I tried different port (TCP and for included android app). The socket connect with the server, but it "hangs" when I try to use read() method (even out of while loop). Authenticator don't work too.

Some info about dvr:

1. Protocol support: TCP/IP, UDP, SMTP, NTP, DHCP, DDNS
2. Video compression: H.264
3. Operating system: linux

I will much appreciate any advices.

Comment: for starter i advise you to have a look how existng application works, try to find what is being send to DVR, and try to replicate it, it might be possible you need to send some commands first to turn on streaming

Comment: Hi I tried to do so using socket connection on iOS, but I am not sure how to pass username and password for that socket.

Comment: Try to connect with the DVR by using VLC (http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/VideoLAN-HOWTO/x549.html). If any of the supported protocols works, then try to gather the stream with Video4Linux by using the binding V4L4J (https://code.google.com/p/v4l4j/). It uses FFMPEG so many codecs are supported.

There is many examples for fetching an stream https://code.google.com/p/v4l4j/wiki/Examples

Comment: If it works under TCP/IP I would use wireshark http://www.wireshark.org/download.html to intercept communication to see what are you sending (if anything) and receiving and go from there.

Comment: I am looking into V4L4J project. Do you know how vMEye app connects to DVR using the username and password? I tried using RTSP, but It seems that it does not use RTSP to connect to DVR.